# How to check how much "free" iGPU VRAM the system have in MB?

Tags: memory, gpu

How to check how much **free** iGPU VRAM the system have?

I thought it was a simple easy task, but so far I don't find any useful result by googling.

I knew how much VRAM I have. I knew I could run `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataTyp` at cml. I knew I could check GPU % of each application in **Activity Monitor** > **% GPU** Column. I knew there is **Activity Monitor** > **Window** > **GPU History** Window etc..

But none of them tell me how much iGPU VRAM the system uses and how much free VRAM is in `MB` value.

Do anyone know how to check the info?

CML way is preferred.

if not, Built-in tool is preferred.

if not, Open source tool is preferred.

if not, Free tool is prefered.

Thank you very much.

**Edited:** I don't want to use a paid app for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this using the iStats Menu program, which is a paid app that you can try for free for 14 days:

https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/

Note that you'll probably find that the VRAM is maxed out, and there's much you can really use this metric for unless you happen to be a developer actively developing your own software using the GPU. In that case, you should use the free Instruments tool from Apple instead.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Actually I knew iStats Menu can do that before asking this question. I don't want to use a paid app..

Comment: You should have written that in the question then 

Comment: Sorry.. I have upvoted your answer and updated the question too. Thanks a lot. 